# why pool and cached method has almost same runtime?

Tags: python, caching, multiprocessing

When I run code without `lru_cache`  I get this result. Which is understandable

with multiprocessing
time took 0.4375
without multiprocessing
time took8.8125

But when I run using `lru_cache` this is the result:
Test1
with multiprocessing
time took 0.34375
without multiprocessing
time took 0.3125

Test2
with multiprocessing
time took 3.234375
without multiprocessing
time took 3.046875

He we can clearly see without multiprocessing is almost equal or little faster than multiprocessing method. What's the reason for this? I understand that creating process is overhead but work list is very huge (10 million) so I guess  chunk size is not too small. Or am I doing this wrong way?

Code explanation:
**oddlist ()**  take number and return the sum of all odd nums in that range
**oddcount** is a tuple contains 10 million random numbers

Code:

```
import os
from random import randint
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def oddlist(num):
    return reduce(add,(i for i in range(num) if i&1))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    oddcounts=tuple(randint(10,50) for i in range(10000000))
    print('with multiporcessing')
    s=time.process_time()
    with Pool(12) as p:
        mp=p.map(oddlist, oddcounts)
    e=time.process_time()
    print(f'time took {e-s}')
    print('witout multiporcessing')
    s=time.process_time()
    z=tuple(oddlist(i) for i in oddcounts)
    e=time.process_time()
    print(f'time took {e-s}')
```

Comment: Every process is going to have it's own cache, making the caching less efficient.

Comment: @KlausD. Don't they each get around 833,333 numbers from 10 to 50, so will still get get 99.995% cache hits?

Comment: As an aside, `reduce(add, whatever)` - > `sum(whatever)`. indeed, `reduce` is pretty anti-idiomatic, but at least don't use it to re-invent the wheel

Comment: Also, **please** always provide a [mcve]. We should be able to copy and paste your code and run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each process has its own cache, so while using  multiprocessing,  caching is 1/12th as effective as it would otherwise be. There are only 40 possible input values to oddlist. In the multiprocessing case, each process computes all 40, then uses the cache. Without  multiprocessing, all 40 are only computed once. So, in addition to the overhead of starting the processes, each process does more work than it would need to if caching were working as intended. Also, there is  a cost to pass the work to be done in each process to it, and passing  the result back.